# Objective C Make A @ Method

Tags: objective-c

I am currently programming in Objective C and I was wondering, Is it possible to make static methods with an `@` at the beginning eg. `@selector()` and `@encode`. I have tried doing this with `static` eg. `static BOOL @boolforint(int intValue)` but Xcode won't let me do this. is an `@` function only Xcode default? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want the @?

Comment: Its hard to explain, I don't need it but I just wish to know if it is possible and how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@selector`, `@encode` (and others, e.g. `@YES`, `@NO`, etc.) are *compiler directives*. They are not static methods or even functions.

You can create macros (using `#define`) that look similar but it's not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway I can implement my own compiler directives?

Comment: Well yes. If you download the souce of the compiler, you can do anything there.

Answer (score 0):

There are no static methods in Objective-C.

You can use class methods instead like:

+(void)classMethod

Comment: Yes thank you I know there are methods and instances in classes and seperate static functions but I wish to create a static method that represents a core function beginning with @ like @selector, etc...

Comment: as Sulthan said those are compiler directives. What you need to do?

Comment: This is not compulsory to me but I just really wish to know more stuff on objc